# show full width vertical nav items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to implement the nav features similar to http://www.startupturkey.com/ when hamburger icon is clicked. How can i do so? I am using semantic ui for css framework. Here is what i have tried?

https://jsfiddle.net/0taywkL5/

```
<header class="header">
      <!-- <i class="reorder icon"></i> -->
      <a href="#" class="header__logo">LOGO</a>
      <i class="content icon header-icon" style="float: right;"></i>
      <div class="ui vertical menu" style="display:none;">
        <a class="active teal item">
          Blog
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Discussion
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Features
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Team
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="home-header show">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="request-invitation">
        <h2>REQUEST AN INVITATION</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="short-intro">
        <h1>HEADING IN THE MIDDLE OF IMAGE</h1>
      </div>
    </section>


body {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.header {
  height: 66px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

i.content.icon.header-icon{
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.71);
  font-size: 3em;
}

i.remove.icon.header-icon{
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.71);
  font-size: 3em;
}

.header .menu a{
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.header__logo {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 25px;
  float: left;
}

/* MENU */
.menu {
  float: right;
}

section.home-header.show {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1Hv_aIqhvzszFyuTWFJlxJzqsQI0Y-eQmCFto8j9mRTER3GMFlI5vQS83) center;
}

section.home-header {
    background: #000;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -moz-transition: 2s background-color;
    -o-transition: 2s background-color;
    -webkit-transition: 2s background-color;
    transition: 2s background-color;
}

.request-invitation {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 25px;
    color: rgba(27, 28, 29, 0.77);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.short-intro {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10em 20em;
    /* left: 50%; */
}

.short-intro h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}

.short-intro h3{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I think position:absolute you missed for this class - .ui.vertical.menu

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this website: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp
There you can see how to create "side-nav" for you it would be a top-nav ^^.

Here a working jsfiddle which just needs some more styling:
https://jsfiddle.net/feys00e6

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
```

Comment: I dont see open block. I only see close icon and when i click nothing happens. If i comment position: fixed, both open and close is shown and when i click open , the nav items will be shown as in jsfiddle.

Comment: You actually just need to copy & paste the fiddle, or take a look at the w3schools website